# Hibernate query params - bracket notation #{# }

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

let's say I have the following hibernate query:

```
 @Query("""
        SELECT s FROM Submission s
            WHERE s.id = :#{#submissionId}
        """)
Submission getSubmissionById(@Param("submissionId") Long submissionId);
```

In our code I find two different ways of putting the parameter into the query:

`:#{#submissionId}` and `:submissionId` (without the brackets and #)

Is there a particular reason to use either of those? As far as I know they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I haven't really seen the first format before and it's quite a bit harder to read. I doubt there's any functional difference.

Comment: Spring Data repositories support [some limited use of SpEL in queries](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions). The '#' syntax is an example of that, though it probably doesn't make much sense in your example.